# what satisfy maximal cliques

Tags: graph-theory

[image: maximal cliques]

are these correct
I am very confused what satisfy maximal cliques

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a clique to me maximal, it needs two things:

- To be a clique (obviously)
- No new vertex can be added and still make it a clique

All your listed cliques are cliques, so that's fine. However, EIF is not a maximal clique, as you can add H and get the clique EIFH. Likewise, FGH is not maximal because you can add E.